# Stored procedure to Insert data into table with select statement and argument parameter

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-5.7, insert

I am creating a stored procedure which will populate my table with data passed from procedure argument and from other table.

I have a table with three columns (cart_id, product, sold_quantity). Now, I want to populate this table with a stored procedure. In this table, `cart_id` will be passed as stored procedure argument while other two columns are populated from another table. I want to insert latest 10 rows from other table and for all these rows, the `cart_id` will be same

First I tried,

```
BEGIN

insert into my_table (cart_id, product, sold_quantity) VALUES (cart_id, (Select `product`, `sold_quantity` from other_table limit 10))

END
```

Here, cart_id is passed in procedure argument. This obviously does not work as the coulmn count does not match.
So, I tried,

```
BEGIN

insert into my_table (cart_id, product, sold_quantity) VALUES (cart_id, (Select `product` from other_table limit 10), (Select  `sold_quantity` from other_table limit 10))

END
```

This returns error `Subquery returns more than 1 row`

Is there any way I can populate my table with data from a combination of argument parameter and other table?

Comment: Hello @Charlieface, If you read my question properly, you will know the provided link is completely different than the question I have posted. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I really don't understand why. You want to know how to insert multiple rows and columns from one table to another (with the slight tweak of an extra fixed column). This is done using `INSERT ... SELECT ...` which is what that answer shows.

Comment: Yes @Charlieface, that small tweak was the reason I had to add a new question because I had not idea how to do it. No worries, I got the solution from Ergest's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `VALUES` in your particular case. Use `INSERT INTO SELECT`.

Query.

```
insert into my_table (cart_id, 
                      product, 
                      sold_quantity
                      ) 
select  cart_id, 
        product,
        sold_quantity
from other_table limit 10 ;
```

Example
Consider the following data

```
create table other_table(
    product int ,
    sold_quantity int ); 

insert into other_table values  (1,10), (2,10), (3,10), (4,10), (5,10), 
(1,10), (2,10), (3,10), (4,10), (5,10);

create table my_table(
    cart_id int,
    product int(9) ,
    sold_quantity int );
```

Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_into_table(cart_id int )
BEGIN       
   insert into my_table (cart_id, 
                      product, 
                      sold_quantity
                      ) 
   select  cart_id, 
           product,
           sold_quantity
   from other_table limit 10 ;
END;
```

Procedure call

```
call insert_into_table(5);
```

Result

```
select * from my_table;

cart_id product sold_quantity
   5       1    10
   5       2    10
   5       3    10
   5       4    10
   5       5    10
   5       1    10
   5       2    10
   5       3    10
   5       4    10
   5       5    10
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/PWCgNy0j